# Action Script 3 error 1023: Implication Override & error 1021: Duplication function Definition. Look here and cant find the answer

Tags: actionscript-3

## Help

I'm a university student currently studying action script 3 flash game coding and I've
    come across the two coding problems that are within the title. 1023 and 1021.

I've looked at multiple forums and posts (even on here) to find a solution but everything
    I try just doesn't seem to work at all. I'm tearing my hair out over this I just want it
    to work. If anyone can help me out by point out what the heck is wrong I'd greatly 
    appreciated it!

```
var loader:URLLoader;
var allWords:Array;
var thisWord:String;
var textContainer:MovieClip
var textFields:Array;
var textStyle:TextFormat;
var underline:MovieClip;
var numCorrect:uint;
var totalLetters:uint;
var misses:uint;
var missiesToLose:uint;


function initializeGame():void
{
loader = new URLLoader();
allWords = new Array();

textContainer = new MovieClip();
textFields = new Array()

textStyle = new TextFormat();

textStyle.font = "Courier New";
textStyle.size = 48;
textStyle.bold = true;

guesses_txt.text = "";

numCorrect = 0;

textContainer.y = 320.30;
addChild(textContainer);

loader.load(new URLRequest("words.txt"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, textLoaded);
guess_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, guess);
 }    

  function textLoaded(event:Event):void
{
var tempText:TextField;
var stringOfWords:String = event.target.data;
allWords = stringOfWords.split(",");
thisWord = allWords[7]; 
totalLetters = thisWord.length;

//characters loop
for(var i:uint = 0; i < thisWord.length; i++)
{
    tempText = new TextField();
    tempText.defaultTextFormat = textStyle; //font type
    tempText.name = "textField" + i; 


    tempText.width = 48;
    tempText.x = i * tempText.width;
    tempText.selectable = false;
    textContainer.addChild(tempText);
    textFields.push(tempText);

    if(thisWord.charAt(i) != " ")
    {
        underline = new Underline();
        underline.x = tempText.x + tempText.width /3;
        underline.y = tempText.y + tempText.height/2 + 5;
        textContainer.addChild(underline);
    }
  }
  textContainer.x = stage.stageWidth /2 - textContainer.width/2;
   }

   function guess(Event:MouseEvent):void
   {
var wordLC:String = thisWord.toLowerCase();

if(guess_txt.text != "") 
{
    if(wordLC.indexOf(guess_txt.text) != -1)
    {
        for(var i:uint = 0; i < textFields.length; i++)
        {
            if(wordLC.charAt(i) == guess_txt.text)
            {
                textFields[i].text = thisWord.charAt(i);
                numCorrect ++;
                if(numCorrect >= totalLetters)
                {
                    gotoAndPlay(2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(guesses_txt.text == "") 
    {
        guesses_txt.appendText(guess_txt.text);
    }
    else
    {
        guesses_txt.appendText("," + guess_txt.text)
    }
}
guess_txt.text = "";
}

initializeGame();
```

Comment: With your posted code, personally I can't see where is the problem exactly, so could you add more details about the errors or maybe if you can provide your fla ... ?

Comment: Run the project in Debug mode and it should tell you what lines have the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that code goes on a keyframe. I haven't done much keyframe programming (for obvious reasons) but if that keyframe is being played a second time the entire code is run again and duplication of variables and functions might occur. Check if your movieclip is hitting that particular keyframe a second time. If yes, you can solve that by an initialisation switch (any shape or form you desire) or by working on your library class at class level.